# NetSuite - Custom Fields - Assigned to Addressbook but cant access using JS

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am currently writing a script on the Sales Order to pull fetch a custom field attached to the selected shipping address. I am able to pull all of the address fields (city,zip, etc) but I am unable to figure out how to access any of the attached custom fields to the address.

Example script:

```js
var custid = document.getElementById("hddn_entity_fs").value;
var shiptoid = document.getElementById("hddn_shipaddresslist2").value;

var customer = nlapiLoadRecord("customer", custid);
var itemCount = customer.getLineItemCount('addressbook');

for (var i = 1; i < itemCount; i++) {
  if (customer.getLineItemValue('addressbook', 'id', i) == shiptoid) {

    //this works
    var zip = customer.getLineItemValue('addressbook', 'zip', i);
    console.log('zip:' + zip);

    //this does not work
    var custrecord19 = customer.getLineItemValue('addressbook', 'custrecord19', i);
    console.log('custrecord19:' + custrecord19);
  }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something simple. Any help greatly appreciated!

Zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fields on address are actually on the address record

so something like:

SS1.0 dynamic mode. Apparently server side only.

```
var customer = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', custid, {recordmode:'dynamic'});
...
customer.selectLineItem('addressbook', i);
var addr = customer.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
console.log(addr.getFieldValue('custrecord19'));
```

or SS1 server side not dynamic

```
var addr = custRec.viewLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress', i);
console.log(addr.getFieldValue('custrecord19'));
```

SS2.0 works client or server side

```
var addr = custRec.getSublistSubrecord({sublistId:'addressbook', fieldId:'addressbookaddress', line:i});
console.log(addr.getValue({fieldId:'custrecord19'}));
```

It's quite doable for an account to have a mix of SS1 and SS2 scripts.

In terms of getting this to work I'd suggest changing your current client script to SS2.

below is a skeleton client script:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x 
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord', 'N/ui/message', 'N/url', 'N/https', 'N/search'],
    function(rec, msg, url, http, search) {



        return {
            fieldChanged : function(){ console.log('fired field changed');},
            postSourcing: function(){ console.log('fired sourcing');}
        };
    });
```

Comment: I tried both and both throw errors. With your object of custRec, is that supposed to be the customer object in my example above? If so, I get a: customer.viewLineItemSubrecord is not a function or a customer.getSublistSubrecord is not a function.

Comment: Your script is SS1.My SS1 sample used getValue instead of getFieldValue. fixed and a client side sample added.

Comment: Using the SS1 client side example, I get TypeError customer.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function ;) (Thanks for the quick replies BTW!)

Comment: You didn't reload the record dynamic mode.

Comment: I did changed it to what you have. Still getting "editCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function" I have tried nlapiEditCurrentLineItemSubrecord and viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord as well, both throw the "is not a function" error.

Comment: I also just renamed the "customer" var to "custx" to make sure there were no collisions with other variables. No different. I have spent quite a bit of time looking and testing what others say works ... only to end up at the same place with functions not available.

Comment: A couple of those snippets started as production code. You need to understand what mode you are accessing the record from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210892/discussion-between-zip-and-bknights).